# replace RichTextBox content binds to empty string

Tags: wpf, binding, richtextbox

In WPF(.Net 4.5) I have RichTextBox in my xaml

```
    <RichTextBox Height="40" Width="100">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="{Binding TestRichTextBox}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

in and ViewModel I have this Property

```
string testRichTextBox;
public string TestRichTextBox
{
    get { return testRichTextBox; }
    set 
    {
        if (testRichTextBox == value)
            return;
        testRichTextBox = value;
        onPropertyChanged("TestRichTextBox"); 
    }
}
```

scenario :

1. RichTextBox has content
2. select all text (ctrl+A)
3. paste new text

in ViewModel I have breakpoint on set method, new `Value` is empty string.

Is this normal behavior or a bug?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Could you please try this and check if `var text` is returning any value?

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // "tb" is a richtextBox
    DataObject.AddPastingHandler(tb, OnPaste);
}

private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    var isText = e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText, true);
    if (!isText) return;

    var text = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText) as string;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. still set to empty string and other change has no effect to text box.

Comment: after paste event, control receives empty string value and then binging is broken.

Comment: Select all and replace text delete `Paragraph` object and create new Paragraph. Then binding won't exist any more.

Comment: No, I use `Document` property of RichTextBox.